# Receiving video stream to VLC on PC from Android

Tags: android

I want to stream the video from android phone camera to VLC media player running on PC.

I have written a sample code to stream the video to the specific IP on my local network using `MediaRecorder`. The app on phone is working but I am not able to get the stream in VLC media player.

Code of my android app to stream the video to the network:

```
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.8");
    Socket soc=new Socket(serverAddr,8210);
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(soc);
    tempRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor()); 
    tempRecorder.prepare();
```

Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong or how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media recorder is for recording. The output file you have specified will have the recorded video and you will ship the file to the server to be played as a one video file. I hope you are doing all this:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
...
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```

Also read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFile%28java.lang.String%29):

> public void **setOutputFile** (String path)
>
> Sets the path of the output file to be produced. Call this after setOutputFormat() but before prepare().

But if you want to stream the video frame by frame to the your PC, you need to capture each frame in the `onPreviewFrame` method of the `Camera.PreviewCallback`. From this callback transfer the byte array to your server. This way you will have a continuous stream of image frames from device camera to your server.

Comment: Thanks! So I need to implement the methods in Camrea.PreviewCallback.

Comment: Yes, you should stream from the call back. If you simply want to transfer a video you can record from media record and send the file to server

Comment: I have implemented frame by frame method as you suggested and I got what I am looking for, Thanks again!

Comment: @Vinod: I'm curious, what framerate and quality do you get with the preview callback? Have your tried on various devices?

Comment: @olivierg: I had implemented this and is working. I had also tested it on various devices. But the current problem is frame rate. I am getting only 2-3 fps and still working on it to increase it to 14-16 fps.

Comment: @VinodMaurya This is an old thread.. is there any luck on getting it to increase the fps? Thanks

Comment: @andrewliu - yes, got fps around 12-15 by compressing the frames, but now using gstreamer and is working fine now.